# Accessing contents in a div in a controller action (ASP.NET MVC3 Application)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a div in my form in my view. Using javascript I use jqwidgets to generate the combo box.

Now in the form I also have the submit button. The rest of the contents in the form are passed as request parameters to the controller action(though I use a model - so they are automatically mapped), what happens to this div contents.

Are they also passed to the controller? If so how can we access it in the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content in your div is inside the form and the components are correctly created, they'll be on the `Request.Form` in your controller when you send the form.

You can access them through `Request.Form["componentName"],` and if it's name attribute matches with a parameter in your model class it should be able to directly bind it.

Keep in mind that javascript created content is effectively added to *DOM*. When you send your form the whole collection of form components inside the *DOM* is sent into your request. You just need to check that components are correctly created and identified (I mean... they have a correct name attribute)

Answer (score 1):

The **jqxComboBox widget** has a hidden Input. Just set the DIV tag's name attribute and the value of the ComboBox will be passed, too.

To get the value of the **jqwidgets** combobox, you can type:

```
var value = $("#combobox").val();
```

Comment: There is no name attribute for div tag.

Comment: You can put any attribute to anything. Set the "name" attribute to the DIV tag and the Combobox value will be passed when you submit the Form. jQWidgets have a Demo with ComboBox submit in the PHP Integration demos and there it is done in that way.

Answer (score 0):

When form is posted only inputs, selects and textarea values are passed to server when these elements:

1. have name
2. are not disabled
3. are inside form (or has `form` attribute with form id as value)

You will almost never need to pass whole html element to action, but if you will need, then pass it through ajax or write it inside hidden input